# Calling a PHP script from a python file gives error /bin/sh: path: Permission denied

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to run a PHP script in the terminal from within python, but I can't seem to acces the PHP file

My python code for calling the PHP script is:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("/Users/cedrique/documents/test.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

However this gives me a permission denied error:

`/bin/sh: /Users/cedrique/documents/test.php: Permission denied`

Can I give it the correct rights? OR maybe I have to put it in another folder?

Thank you!

Comment: try to cd to `/Users/cedrique/documents/` and issue a `ls -la`. Who owns the file? What kind of permission are in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `php` with the script name as an argument.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["php", "/Users/cedrique/documents/test.php"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

There's also no need for `shell=True` here, since you're not using any shell operations.

Comment: Thank you! This did it!